# How to see request and response data in node soap?

Tags: node.js, debugging, soap-client, node-soap

I am trying to consume a soap api using [node soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap). My response cannot be parsed and I wonder how to see the request and response data to console to ease the error finding process.

Answer (score 3):

As node soap uses the request library, one can debug it via:

```
NODE_DEBUG=request node src/index.js
```

as pointed out [request's Readme.md](https://github.com/request/request#debugging):

> Debugging
>
> There are at least three ways to debug the operation of `request`:
>
> 1. Launch the node process like `NODE_DEBUG=request node script.js`    (`lib,request,otherlib` works too).
> 2. Set `require('request').debug = true` at any time (this does the same thing    as #1).
> 3. Use the [request-debug module](https://github.com/request/request-debug) to    view request
>      and response headers and bodies.

Answer (score 1):

To see the generated SOAP XML request you can use [this](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientlastrequest---the-property-that-contains-last-full-soap-request-for-client-logging):

> Client.***lastRequest*** - the property that contains last full soap request for client logging